# R: Formatted output from biglm

Tags: r

Is there an way to have a nicely formatted output of summary(biglm)? R2HTML, which works very nicely for summary(lm), does not retain formatting at all.

```
library(biglm)
library(R2HTML)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100))
L <- lm(y~x,data=d)
LL <- biglm(y~x,data=d)
HTML(summary(L),file="tmp1.html")
HTML(summary(LL),file="tmp2.html")
```

The HTML file `tmp1.html` has pretty formatting: the HTML file `tmp2.html` contains "raw" captured output from `summary.biglm()`

Comment: reproducible example would help

Comment: The syntax for biglm is exactly the same as lm: model = lm(Y ~ X, data=MyData) - just replace lm with biglm. Whereas R2HTML prints out the summary for lm nicely with library(R2HTML); HTML(model, file="filepath"), all formatting is lost when I use biglm instead of lm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to find out what's going on here you have to do a bit of digging into the methods.  `HTML` is a generic function, so it goes looking for a specific function that it can use on a particular object, based on its class.  The results of `summary(lm(...))` are of class `summary.lm`; the equivalent for `biglm` is (unsurprisingly) `summary.biglm`.  If you run

```
methods("HTML")
```

you'll see all the methods defined for `HTML`; most of these have asterisks after their names, which indicates that they are hidden within the namespace of the `R2HTML` package.  To see the method for class `foo` you need `R2HTML:::foo`.  There is an `R2HTML:::HTML.summary.lm` function, but no corresponding `HTML.summary.biglm` function, so calling `HTML(summary(LL))` (where `LL` is a `biglm` object) reverts to the `R2HTML:::HTML.default` function, which just captures the output in a fairly raw form.

If you were lucky, and the internal structures of `summary.lm` and `summary.biglm` were sufficiently similar, you could just say `HTML.summary.biglm <- R2HTML:::HTML.summary.lm` and be done with it, but this doesn't work because the internal structures of `summary.lm` and `summary.biglm` are too different.

The next thing to do would be to dump the definition of `R2HTML:::HTML.summary.lm` and work through its guts, changing it as appropriate (e.g., for a first pass: use `dput()` to dump `R2HTML:::HTML.summary.lm` to a file; add a bit of code at the top of the file to define `HTML.summary.biglm` as that function; try `HTML(summary(LL))` and identify where you hit an error (possibly using `debug()` to trace through); fix the appropriate piece of the file; repeat until done.

One of the problems is that some of the differences between the internal structures of `summary.lm` and `summary.biglm` are not just cosmetic, but are design differences -- for example, `summary.lm` includes a copy of the residuals (try `names(summary(L))` or `str(summary(L))` where `L` is an `lm` fit), which just doesn't make sense for a `biglm` object. (This is a short way of saying that this ended up being too big a job for me to undertake as a quick answer to a SO question ...)

Good luck ...